# Many 404 errors with email address at the end

Tags: .htaccess, url, http-status-code-404

I'm getting a lot of 404 error notices (about 200 of them) from my website for URLs that have my email address at the end. For example: http://mysite.com/blog/myname@mysite.com

My first thought is to use .htaccess to redirect the URLs to the real URL without the email address at the end but I don't know how to do that. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is the real URL where they should be redirected?

Comment: In the example above, it would redirect to http://mysite.com/blog/

Comment: I got it and provided an answer for that below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule RewriteRule ^(.*?/?)(?=[^/]*$)[^@]*@ /$1 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! My only question remaining is that many of the URLs are different -- i.e. http://mysite.com/feedback/myname@mysite.com or http://mysite.com/myname@mysite.com -- will this simply remove the email address and leave the rest of the URL intact?

Comment: Okay changed my code to make it generic to handle all those cases.